# Mariadb 5.5, CREATE OR REPLACE, doesn't work

Tags: mariadb

I have some FUNCTIONS and PROCEDURES in `mysql Ver 15.1 Distrib 10.1.23-MariaDB, for Linux (x86_64) using readline 5.1`. The code for them are like this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE DEFINER=`root`@`%` FUNCTION `some_name`(_IN_FECHA_PROYECCION date) RETURNS double
BEGIN, etc...
END
```

Everything goes well when I create those functions or procedures through a command line with Laravel (php artisan migrate). But when I did it on other machine with `mysql  Ver 15.1 Distrib 5.5.59-MariaDB, for Linux (x86_64) using readline 5.1` mysql returns me errors like:

```
SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version
for the right syntax to use near '=`root`@`localhost` FUNCTION `some_name`(_IN_FECHA_PROYECCION da'
at line 1 (SQL: REPLACE DEFINER=`root`@`%` FUNCTION `some_name`(_IN_FECHA_PROYECCION date) RETURNS double
BEGIN, etc...
END
```

Well, I removed the "OR REPLACE" from the code and now MariaDB 5.5 has no problem creating the procedures/functions. So my question is, what's the problem with REPLACE at MariaDB 5.5? I couldn't find anything on the docs of MariaDB.

Comment: Hmm, I see: https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/create-procedure/#comment_2756 it's available since 10.1.4  :(

Comment: What came before the `=`?

Comment: @RickJames look at my code `CREATE OR REPLACE DEFINER=`root`@`%` FU` etc...

Comment: Could it be that you should say only `DEFINER=root`?  That is, without the 'host' part.

Comment: But as I wrote, I have no problems in MariaDB 10, it's in MariaDB 5 the problem, check the link in my first comment. The problem is with the "OR REPLACE":  `...awesome OR REPLACE feature, which seems to have been available since 10.1.4...`